# Unable to find version 'Y' of package 'X'

Tags: .net, nuget, nuget-package

I'm using the `nuget.exe` in a linux pc and while it works for many packages I'm having the following issue with a couple of them.

The idea is to download locally a NuGet package into as specific directory.

While the search command is working (returns the package)

```
$ nuget search "package_name" -Source 'https://nuget.pkg.github.com/org/index.json' -Prerelease
```

```
====================
Source: github
--------------------
> package_name | 1.0.0-develop-c313463.64 | Downloads: 49
  Package Description
--------------------
```

If I try to download it I'm getting the following error:

```
$ nuget install "package_name" -OutputDirectory ./download -Version "1.0.0-develop-c313463.64" -Source https://nuget.pkg.github.com/org/index.json -DependencyVersion Ignore -Prerelease
```

```
Feeds used:
  https://nuget.pkg.github.com/org/index.json

  CACHE https://nuget.pkg.github.com/org/package_name/index.json
Unable to find version '1.0.0-develop-c313463.64' of package 'package_name'.
```

I also tried to clean all caches using `dotnet nuget locals --clear all` without any success.

By adding more verbosity to the install command, I'm getting:

```
NuGet Version: 6.7.0.127
Feeds used:
  https://nuget.pkg.github.com/org/index.json

  CACHE https://nuget.pkg.github.com/org/package_name/index.json
Unable to find version '1.0.0-develop-c313463.64' of package 'package_name'.
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find version '1.0.0-develop-c313463.64' of package 'package_name'.
  at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.GetSourceRepository (NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackageIdentity packageIdentity, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] sourceRepositories, NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.SourceCacheContext sourceCacheContext, NuGet.Common.ILogger logger) [0x0033b] in <6484ae034e4e4be89d06d0b5f786e57c>:0
  at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.PreviewInstallPackageAsync (NuGet.ProjectManagement.NuGetProject nuGetProject, NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackageIdentity packageIdentity, NuGet.PackageManagement.ResolutionContext resolutionContext, NuGet.ProjectManagement.INuGetProjectContext nuGetProjectContext, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] primarySources, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] secondarySources, NuGet.Versioning.VersionRange versionRange, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x00c0f] in <6484ae034e4e4be89d06d0b5f786e57c>:0
  at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.PreviewInstallPackageAsync (NuGet.ProjectManagement.NuGetProject nuGetProject, NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackageIdentity packageIdentity, NuGet.PackageManagement.ResolutionContext resolutionContext, NuGet.ProjectManagement.INuGetProjectContext nuGetProjectContext, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] primarySources, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] secondarySources, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x00096] in <6484ae034e4e4be89d06d0b5f786e57c>:0
  at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.InstallPackageAsync (NuGet.ProjectManagement.NuGetProject nuGetProject, NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackageIdentity packageIdentity, NuGet.PackageManagement.ResolutionContext resolutionContext, NuGet.ProjectManagement.INuGetProjectContext nuGetProjectContext, NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.PackageDownloadContext downloadContext, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] primarySources, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] secondarySources, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x000a1] in <6484ae034e4e4be89d06d0b5f786e57c>:0
  at NuGet.CommandLine.InstallCommand.InstallPackageAsync (System.String packageId, NuGet.Versioning.NuGetVersion version, System.String installPath) [0x004fc] in <6484ae034e4e4be89d06d0b5f786e57c>:0
  at NuGet.CommandLine.Command.Execute () [0x000ea] in <6484ae034e4e4be89d06d0b5f786e57c>:0
  at NuGet.CommandLine.Program.MainCore (System.String workingDirectory, System.String[] args) [0x001c7] in <6484ae034e4e4be89d06d0b5f786e57c>:0
```

Comment: If clearing the http-cache (via `dotnet nuget locals --clear all`) didn't work, this suggests that GitHub's implementation of the NuGet protocol may be buggy. Is the version in the package's nupkg/nuspec match the version in the error message, exactly? NuGet treats both version and package id as case insensitive, and will always lower case both (and well as normalizing leading zeros in the version) when making web requests. If the package version uses `Develop` rather than `develop`, then maybe it's an edge case that GitHub's implementation didn't handle how NuGet expects.